# Error when Creating Channel Using Hyperledger Fabric Node JS

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I'm trying to create a channel with the Fabric SDK node.js. When I create the channel through the bash commands, I have no problems (you can see the code below), but when I use the node.js SDK I got some errors.
I am using TLS and client authentication. I can't realize what the error means and how to solve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Node JS code to create Channel, it was executed in host machine:

```
var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
var fs=require('fs');
var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

// Obtain tls cert and key from client.
let clientcert = fs.readFileSync('/home/rosalva40/Documentos/Own2/Own/data/tls/peer1-org1-cli-client.crt');
let clientkey = fs.readFileSync('/home/rosalva40/Documentos/Own2/Own/data/tls/peer1-org1-cli-client.key');
fabric_client.setTlsClientCertAndKey(clientcert.toString(),clientkey.toString())



//Orderer configuration
let pem1 = fs.readFileSync('/home/rosalva40/Documentos/Own2/Own/data/org0-ca-chain.pem');
const connectionopts = {
    pem: pem1.toString()
};
var order = fabric_client.newOrderer('grpcs://localhost:9101', connectionopts)


//setup identity admin
let cert = fs.readFileSync('/home/rosalva40/Documentos/Own2/Own/data/orgs/org1/admin/msp/signcerts/cert.pem');
let pk = fs.readFileSync('/home/rosalva40/Documentos/Own2/Own/data/orgs/org1/admin/msp/keystore/b17b8a06b4928a037e621cc784cac4f8a4913087c95c68162ecae6189993a1fa_sk');
const  mspid = 'org1MSP';
fabric_client.setAdminSigningIdentity(pk, cert, mspid);


// Setup create channel
var chanelName = 'mychannel';
const envelope = fs.readFileSync('/home/rosalva40/Documentos/Own2/Own/data/channel.tx');
channelConfig = fabric_client.extractChannelConfig(envelope);
signature = fabric_client.signChannelConfig(channelConfig);

const request = {
    name: chanelName,
    orderer: order,
    config: channelConfig,
    signatures : [signature],
    txId : fabric_client.newTransactionID(true)
};


//Create chanel
fabric_client.createChannel(request);
```

When I run createChannel.js, I get the following error in the console:

> 2019-01-17T14:30:42.278Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to
>   connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:9101
>   2019-01-17T14:30:42.283Z - error: [Orderer.js]: Orderer
>   grpcs://localhost:9101 has an error Error: Failed to connect before
>   the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:9101  (node:31051)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to connect before the
>   deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:9101
>       at checkState (/home/rosalva40/fabric-samples/vote/node_modules/fabric-client/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:720:16)
>   (node:31051) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:31051) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

And this is the orderer node log:

> 2019-01-17 16:08:40.977 UTC [grpc] Println -> DEBU 13a grpc:
>   Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection error: desc
>   = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client: EOF" 2019-01-17 16:08:41.987 UTC [grpc] Println -> DEBU
>   13b grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport:  connection
>   error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive
>   the preface from client: EOF" 2019-01-17 16:08:43.572 UTC [grpc]
>   Println -> DEBU 13c grpc: Server.Serve failed to create
>   ServerTransport:  connection error: desc = "transport:
>   http2Server.HandleStreams failed to receive the preface from client:
>   EOF"

This is the bash code executed in a container:

```
DATA=data
CHANNEL_TX_FILE=/$DATA/channel.tx
CHANNEL_NAME=mychannel 

# ORDERER CONNECTION ARGUMENTS
ORDERER_HOST=orderer1-org0
ORDERER_PORT_INT=7050
INT_CA_CHAINFILE=/${DATA}/org0-ca-chain.pem
ORDERER_PORT_ARGS="-o $ORDERER_HOST:$ORDERER_PORT_INT --tls --cafile $INT_CA_CHAINFILE --clientauth"

export CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE=/$DATA/tls/peer1-org1-cli-client.crt
export CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE=/$DATA/tls/peer1-org1-cli-client.key

ORDERER_CONN_ARGS="$ORDERER_PORT_ARGS --keyfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE --certfile $CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE"

#ORGANIZATION ADMIN ENVIROMENT ARGUMENTS
ORG_ADMIN_HOME=/${DATA}/orgs/org1/admin
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$ORG_ADMIN_HOME/msp
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1MSP

#CHANNEL CREATE COMMAND
peer channel create --logging-level=DEBUG -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f $CHANNEL_TX_FILE $ORDERER_CONN_ARGS
```

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like the app has problems to connect to the orderer. Try using this method:

```
var Client = require('fabric-client');
var Channel = require('fabric-client').Channel;
const fs = require('fs');
var client = Client.loadFromConfig("config/configfile.yaml");
/**
 * @param {String} channelName Channel name used in configtxgen to create the channel transaction (mychannel)
 * @param {String} channelConfigPath Path of the channel transaction (/home/root/channel-artifacts/channel.tx)
 * @param {String} orderer Orderer name (orderer.example.com)
 * @description Create channel
 */
async createChannel(channelName,orderer, channelConfigPath) {
    var envelope = fs.readFileSync(channelConfigPath);
    var channelConfig = client.extractChannelConfig(envelope);
    let signature = client.signChannelConfig(channelConfig);
    let request = {
        config: channelConfig,
        orderer: client.getOrderer(orderer),
        signatures: [signature],
        name: channelName,
        txId: client.newTransactionID(true)
    };
    const result = await client.createChannel(request)
    return result;
}
```

You can check the structure of the configfile.yaml in this [link](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-network-config.html).
Dont forget to set the client  header in your configfile.yaml

Comment: Can you add little more info like the example parameters, locations